# Sitecore 9.3 install failed with XConnect search indexer service failing to start

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework

Running into a major headache and roadblock I have been googling for a while. It looks like the other questions have different errors, and the closest one said it was a license expiration date issue, which mine is not. I am running into an issue installing Sitecore using the Graphical setup package for XP Single. Using the installer, I get to the final step and fail at task 67 regarding the XConnect service.

Here are my errors:

The error from the GUI is

```
[Error]: Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - LHHxconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker (LHHxconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker)'.
```

Event viewer gives:

**Application Error**

```
Faulting application name: Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe, version: 4.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xd63240ad
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.4770, time stamp: 0x6180883c
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034f38
Faulting process id: 0x1670
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7f358c9130da2
Faulting application path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LHHxconnect.dev.local\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

**.Net Runtime error**

```
Application: Sitecore.XConnectSearchIndexer.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at ‫‍‌​⁭‫‏⁭‏‭⁪‎‮‪⁬‎⁯‪⁪‫⁪‫‏‫‌‎‭‎⁫​⁭‪‫‭‌‏‮⁮‮⁮‮.‎⁬⁬⁫​‪⁪⁪‎‭⁬⁬‪‫⁬‭⁬‭‬‎⁪⁮⁭‪⁯⁭⁬‏⁬⁫⁫‪‮‌⁬‮‫⁬⁯‭‮(‭‪‌‏‪‌⁮⁭‬‎⁪‎‌‍⁫‮⁭‍⁮‫⁬​‏‫‏​⁯⁮‮‏⁯‍‏⁫⁭‮‬⁫⁪‎‮ , String )
   at ‭‪‌‏‪‌⁮⁭‬‎⁪‎‌‍⁫‮⁭‍⁮‫⁬​‏‫‏​⁯⁮‮‏⁯‍‏⁫⁭‮‬⁫⁪‎‮..ctor(String )
   at ⁫‬‮‍‎⁪⁮‍​⁭⁯⁭‭⁬⁬⁯‎⁪‮⁫‮‪‏⁫‮⁬‏⁭‌‪⁭‎‭‌⁪⁯‍‭‪‬‮..ctor(String )
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions.InitializeLicenseCheck(IServiceCollection collection, String licenseFileOrXml)
```

( There is more, but the important bit is to show the license)

**IIS Errors:**

```
App_domain
2021-12-17 09:56:44.275 -08:00 [Error] Exception occurred during instantiating of IndexerHost.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LHHxconnect.dev.local\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\license.xml'.
```

**App_host**

```
2021-12-17 09:56:44.275 -08:00 [Error] Failed to start the indexer host
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\LHHxconnect.dev.local\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Data\license.xml'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
```

It says it can't find the license, but in every location needed for 9.3, the file is there.

This is a fresh install on a VM. I already had Sitecore installed but lost my previous VM so I am reinstalling, but I don't believe I ran into this error previously.

I've tried swapping out licenses in the folder with the one I provide to the GUI (should be the same one), I've double-checked the license is updated, but the company started with 9.3 and the license worked previously, so I am not sure anything changes there. The expiration date is several years out, so no problem there.

I am currently trying to replace the kernalbase.dll just in case, but I am fighting writing access issues for the folder.

Other than that avenue, does anyone have a possible idea of what is holding this installer up?